# Regarding Medical Imaging Libraries in Android

Tags: android, library, api

I am required to show CT Scan images and X-ray images via my Tablet app on Android. An app similar to my requirements has already been developed in IOS ([www.accelarad.com](http://www.accelarad.com)) .Please let me know which 3rd Party APIs are available on Android to make Medical Imaging possible on Android. Open Source are first preference but I might also prefer licensed libraries for better performance.

Comment: In which file format are the images? (I mean file extension or file format specification)

Comment: Very likely to be DICOM but yeah, its worth mentioning that specifically

Comment: The Images are in JPEG only..I have already been provided with the DICOM to JPEG Converter. Now I just need to do all the image manipulating operations on the JPEG operations related to medical diagnostics...

Comment: Could you specify what manipulations you're want to be able to perform? A medical tool might or not exist, but some other tools may do the trick, if we know what you want to do.

Comment: I require to zoomin/zoomout , change the contrast/brightness for the medical images which will be used for diagnostic purposes. Please also check out the link which I have provided as the IOS app clearly shows what is required to be done w.r.t. the medical images.

Answer (score 1):

Despite not being specifically developed for Android, but developed for touch-based devices [1], a study titled as "[Towards Touch-Based Medical Image Diagnosis Annotation](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=3134111)" can be a start for you. In this study, the authors explore the radiologist's receptivity to the current touch device solution. From here, the authors developed several touch prototypes over the [BreastScreening](https://breastscreening.github.io/) project, a project that joins contributions from both [MIMBCD-UI](https://mimbcd-ui.github.io/) and [MIDA](https://mida-project.github.io/) projects. The [BreastScreening](https://breastscreening.github.io/) project aims to develop several *AI-Assisted* techniques [2] to improve the medical diagnostic workflow by automatizing several parts of it. The goal is to develop an **Assistant** promoting a higher Radiology Room (RR) performance and bringing higher health care results for the patient. The [new paradigms](https://medium.com/oppr/applying-new-paradigms-in-human-computer-interaction-to-health-informatics-86d6a7046130) of MI in the Health Informatics (HI) field are many and just started. Hope to help you with this answer.

[1] Francisco M. Calisto, Alfredo Ferreira, Jacinto C. Nascimento, and Daniel Gonçalves. 2017. Towards Touch-Based Medical Image Diagnosis Annotation. In Proceedings of the 2017 ACM International Conference on Interactive Surfaces and Spaces (ISS '17). ACM, New York, NY, USA, 390-395. DOI: https://doi.org/10.1145/3132272.3134111

[2] Maicas, Gabriel, Gustavo Carneiro, Andrew P. Bradley, Jacinto C. Nascimento, and Ian Reid. "Deep reinforcement learning for active breast lesion detection from dce-mri." In International Conference on Medical Image Computing and Computer-Assisted Intervention, pp. 665-673. Springer, Cham, 2017.